# Finding neighbors in string list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list and a set, I would like to find all occurences of an element from the set within the list and get the string to left and right of word in the set.

I have this written right now:

```
unique_set = set(text)
context_key = {}
bad_counter = 0

for i,j in enumerate(unique_set):
    context_list = []
    if j in text:
        context = []
        context.append(text[i-1])
        context.append(text[i])
        context.append(text[i+1])
        if j in context:
            context_list.append(context)
            context_key[j] = context_list
        else:
            bad_counter += 1

print(bad_counter)
print(context_key)
```

This seems to actually iterate through both the set and the list however I put the counter in there to see how many values its missing its not adding up, since the length for the full text list is about 130k, 15k misses should be bad, however ever ONLY 3 k,v pairs are what is throwing me off. This is the output:

```
15928
{'compost': [['gardens', 'compost', 'heaps']], 'extra': [['color', 'hair', 'extra']], 'commercial': [['commercial', 'first', 'came']]}
```

The end goal with this is to append the unique value in the set as the dict key to `context_key` and any lists that contain that value as the dict value for `context_key`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the `uniqueset` you declare is just the `set` built from the input, building it upfront just make your code making more avoidable iterations. I would avoid building the `set` at first and just iterating over the retrieved values.

You will retrieve that same unique data easily from the output dictionary of the following procedure by calling its `keys()` method.

Moreover, being insertion in python `list` O(n) I would avoid using them either. Using a data structure with constant access like `dict` will render the job quicker.

Here is a solution that avoids those pitfalls.

```py
def parse(input_file):

    with open(f'{input_file}', 'r') as f:
        data = f.read().split()

    size = len(data)
    indexes = dict()
    for i, x in enumerate(data):
        if x not in indexes:
            indexes[x] = dict()
        indexes[x][i] = (data[i-1]if i>0 else None, data[i+1]if i<size-2 else None)

    return indexes
```

Comment: Dumb question on my part, but I want to understand what you mean, in this case since `input_file` is already a list, wouldn't I be able to just cast it as a set already instead of having to open a new file?

Comment: The only reason I'm reticent to open a new file is that the input that is being received comes from several other functions that take care of pre-processing and several other tests.

Comment: I understand your point. The opening of the `input_file` is just there to let me/you and others to test the solution. You can happily remove it from there and just take the `data` as argument for the function. On the cast to `set` part, I think it involves actually iterating over all elements.

Comment: just tested it now. MUCH faster 2 minutes compared to lest than .5 seconds

Answer (score 2):

If all you want to do is make a list of the word itself, the word before, and the word after then this should do the trick:

```
text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.".split(" ")

unique_set = set(text)
context_key = {}

for i,j in enumerate(unique_set):
    if i in (0, len(text)-1):
        continue

    indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(text) if x == j]

    contexts = []

    for index in indices:
        this_context = []

        word = j
        word_before = text[i-1]
        word_after = text[i+1]

        this_context.append(word_before)
        this_context.append(word)
        this_context.append(word_after)

        contexts.append(this_context)

    context_key[j] = contexts

print(context_key)
```

Output:

```
{'consectetur': [['Lorem', 'consectetur', 'dolor']], 'proident,': [['ipsum', 'proident,', 'sit']], 'quis': [['dolor', 'quis', 'amet,']], 'labore': [['sit', 'labore', 'consectetur']], 'esse': [['amet,', 'esse', 'adipiscing']], 'ex': [['consectetur', 'ex', 'elit,']], 'ea': [['adipiscing', 'ea', 'sed']], 'aliqua.': [['elit,', 'aliqua.', 'do']], 'aute': [['sed', 'aute', 'eiusmod']], 'reprehenderit': [['do', 'reprehenderit', 'tempor']], 'amet,': [['eiusmod', 'amet,', 'incididunt']], 'veniam,': [['tempor', 'veniam,', 'ut']], 'Duis': [['incididunt', 'Duis', 'labore']], 'pariatur.': [['ut', 'pariatur.', 'et']], 'est': [['labore', 'est', 'dolore']], 'commodo': [['et', 'commodo', 'magna']], 'id': [['dolore', 'id', 'aliqua.']], 'voluptate': [['magna', 'voluptate', 'Ut']], 'cupidatat': [['aliqua.', 'cupidatat', 'enim']], 'velit': [['Ut', 'velit', 'ad']], 'sit': [['enim', 'sit', 'minim']], 'elit,': [['ad', 'elit,', 'veniam,']], 'dolore': [['minim', 'dolore', 'quis'], ['minim', 'dolore', 'quis']], 'consequat.': [['veniam,', 'consequat.', 'nostrud']], 'cillum': [['quis', 'cillum', 'exercitation']], 'minim': [['nostrud', 'minim', 'ullamco']], 'exercitation': [['exercitation', 'exercitation', 'laboris']], 'magna': [['ullamco', 'magna', 'nisi']], 'sunt': [['laboris', 'sunt', 'ut']], 'sint': [['nisi', 'sint', 'aliquip']], 'eu': [['ut', 'eu', 'ex']], 'nulla': [['aliquip', 'nulla', 'ea']], 'laborum.': [['ex', 'laborum.', 'commodo']], 'nostrud': [['ea', 'nostrud', 'consequat.']], 'in': [['commodo', 'in', 'Duis'], ['commodo', 'in', 'Duis'], ['commodo', 'in', 'Duis']], 'incididunt': [['consequat.', 'incididunt', 'aute']], 'ut': [['Duis', 'ut', 'irure'], ['Duis', 'ut', 'irure']], 'culpa': [['aute', 'culpa', 'dolor']], 'mollit': [['irure', 'mollit', 'in']], 'laboris': [['dolor', 'laboris', 'reprehenderit']], 'ipsum': [['in', 'ipsum', 'in']], 'Lorem': [['reprehenderit', 'Lorem', 'voluptate']], 'Excepteur': [['in', 'Excepteur', 'velit']], 'deserunt': [['voluptate', 'deserunt', 'esse']], 'aliquip': [['velit', 'aliquip', 'cillum']], 'tempor': [['esse', 'tempor', 'dolore']], 'ullamco': [['cillum', 'ullamco', 'eu']], 'Ut': [['dolore', 'Ut', 'fugiat']], 'enim': [['eu', 'enim', 'nulla']], 'anim': [['fugiat', 'anim', 'pariatur.']], 'fugiat': [['nulla', 'fugiat', 'Excepteur']], 'irure': [['pariatur.', 'irure', 'sint']], 'occaecat': [['Excepteur', 'occaecat', 'occaecat']], 'nisi': [['sint', 'nisi', 'cupidatat']], 'officia': [['occaecat', 'officia', 'non']], 'dolor': [['cupidatat', 'dolor', 'proident,'], ['cupidatat', 'dolor', 'proident,']], 'non': [['non', 'non', 'sunt']], 'do': [['proident,', 'do', 'in']], 'et': [['sunt', 'et', 'culpa']], 'eiusmod': [['in', 'eiusmod', 'qui']], 'sed': [['culpa', 'sed', 'officia']], 'ad': [['qui', 'ad', 'deserunt']], 'adipiscing': [['officia', 'adipiscing', 'mollit']]}
```

**EDIT:**

The problem with the code you provided is that the index from the `enumerate` is from the **set**, which is not necessarily the same index as it would be in the text.  This means that your word doesn't always appear in `context`, as the words in that context are in alphabetical order from your set, not the list of words in `text`.

Hope that makes some small amount of sense :)

Comment: Running it now, since its a big file its gonna take a second, but I tested it with a sample and it worked so I'm going to mark it as answered, thanks!

Comment: So a `if any(word)` might have been a better solution then?

Comment: I don't quite know what you mean, but possibly... :)